# The number of non-zero quaternary (base 4) digits in a long?

Tags: java, binary, bit-manipulation

Let us start simple. Say you want to find how many 1's in a `long` in its binary representation. For example, how many 1's in 228₁₀? The binary represenation is 11100100₂. We can use `Long.bitCount(228);` which returns `4`.

Now, let us say we will interpret two bits as a single quaternary digit (and the two far-right bits is the first digit):

00₂ = 0₄

01₂ = 1₄

10₂ = 2₄

11₂ = 3₄

Hence, 228₁₀ = 11100100₂ = 3210₄. The goal is to find how many non-zero quaternary digits are there in the binary representation. For examples, 3210₄ yields 3, 121100₄ yields 4, 000032₄ yields 2, etc.

The code of the `Long.bitCount(i);` method from Java's documentation is given by:

```
public static int bitCount(long i) {
    i = i - ((i >>> 1) & 0x5555555555555555L);
    i = (i & 0x3333333333333333L) + ((i >>> 2) & 0x3333333333333333L);
    i = (i + (i >>> 4)) & 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0fL;
    i = i + (i >>> 8);
    i = i + (i >>> 16);
    i = i + (i >>> 32);
    return (int)i & 0x7f;
}
```

The goal is to find how many non-zero quaternary digits are there in the binary representation *without* any types of loops nor the usage of `String`s. I am trying to manipulate the code so that it works for quaternary. This is what I currently have:

```
public static int bitCountQuat(long i) {
    i = i - ((i >>> 2) & 0x3333333333333333L);
    i = (i & 0x3333333333333333L) + ((i >>> 4) & 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0fL);
    i = (i + (i >>> 8)) & 0x00ff00ff00ff00ffL;
    i = i + (i >>> 16);
    i = i + (i >>> 32);
    i = i + (i >>> 64);
    return (int) i & 0x7f7f;
 }
```

For more reference: [Efficient Implementation of Hamming Weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight#Efficient_implementation).

Here are the values from 0 to 9:

```
Binary, desired output, current output
0000,   0,  0
0001,   1,  2
0010,   1,  4
0011,   1,  6
0100,   1,  6
0101,   2,  0
0110,   2,  2
0111,   2,  4
1000,   1,  4
1001,   2,  6
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start by converting all non-zero quaternary digits to 1s ...

```
i = (i & 0x5555555555555555L) | ((i >>  1) & 0x5555555555555555L));
```

... then count the bits in the result.

One way to do that bit count would be to continue from there with

```
i = (i & 0x3333333333333333L) + ((i >>  2) & 0x3333333333333333L));
i = (i & 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0fL) + ((i >>  4) & 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0fL));
i = (i & 0x00ff00ff00ff00ffL) + ((i >>  8) & 0x00ff00ff00ff00ffL));
i = (i & 0x0000ffff0000ffffL) + ((i >> 16) & 0x0000ffff0000ffffL));
i = (i & 0x00000000ffffffffL) +  (i >> 32);
```

, which are the trailing steps of the implementation presented in the Wikipedia article you referenced.

Alternatively, you could use the (whole) implementation of `Long.bitCount()`, or even `Long.bitCount()` itself for the bit counting part.  Its variation has enough fewer operations than the (full) Wikipedia version to be about a wash with the above shortcut version.